# (Esclarecimento) Inteligencia artificial Classificação de palavras (Python)

Tags: classificação, inteligência-artificial

Eu estava tentando fazer algo que suprisse essa necessidade:

- Ler a palavra
- Bater em um dicionario
- E Tentar completar a palavra (se possível)

Por exemplo:

```
ENTRADA: CSA
DICIONARIO ["HOMEM", "CASA", "MULHER"]`
SAIDA: CASA

ENTRADA: OMEM
DICIONARIO ["HOMEM", "CASA", "MULHER"]`
SAIDA: HOMEM

ENTRADA: MUHER
DICIONARIO ["HOMEM", "CASA", "MULHER"]`
SAIDA: MULHER

ENTRADA: JOGO
DICIONARIO ["HOMEM", "CASA", "MULHER"]`
SAIDA: Palavra não definida e/ou desconhecida
```

Eu acabei achando alguns exemplos do scikit-learn e da google, porém não entendi como utiliza-los.

[Documentação scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html)

[Google exemplo](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html)

---

Peço ajuda para esclarecimento do que está a ocorrer nesse código:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

def words(text): return re.findall(r'\w+', text.lower())

WORDS = Counter(words(open('big.txt').read()))

def P(word, N=sum(WORDS.values())): 
//"Probability of `word`."
return WORDS[word] / N

def correction(word): 
//"Most probable spelling correction for word."
return max(candidates(word), key=P)

def candidates(word): 
//"Generate possible spelling corrections for word."
return (known([word]) or known(edits1(word)) or known(edits2(word)) or [word])

def known(words): 
//"The subset of `words` that appear in the dictionary of WORDS."
return set(w for w in words if w in WORDS)

def edits1(word):
//"All edits that are one edit away from `word`."
letters    = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
splits     = [(word[:i], word[i:])    for i in range(len(word) + 1)]
deletes    = [L + R[1:]               for L, R in splits if R]
transposes = [L + R[1] + R[0] + R[2:] for L, R in splits if len(R)>1]
replaces   = [L + c + R[1:]           for L, R in splits if R for c in letters]
inserts    = [L + c + R               for L, R in splits for c in letters]
return set(deletes + transposes + replaces + inserts)

def edits2(word): 
//"All edits that are two edits away from `word`."
return (e2 for e1 in edits1(word) for e2 in edits1(e1))
```

Comment: Você precisa corrigir depois de digitado ou durante a digitação? O comportamento do corretor deve contar com feedback implicito ou ele não precisa aprender com a frequencia de erros dele? Você vai retirar as stopwords? O codigo basicamente usa a frequencia dos termos pra calcular e fornecer a combinação mais provavel de letras para a palavra. Basicamente ele sugere a frequentemente mais 'parecida' ou provavel.

Comment: As palavras virão de uma base de texto já digitadas, por exemplo de uma planilha, na próxima coluna pretendo colocar a porcentagem(em decimal) de ser a palavra do dicionario e a palavra do dicionario na próxima coluna...
Algo como
|Palavra|Porcentagem|Possível palavra|
|Casa|1|Casa|
|Caa|%|Casa|

Comment: @Intruso Obrigado mano, eu acabei estudando por conta um pouco de estatística e probabilidade que é o que o código usa... Mas mesmo assim MUITO obrigado pelo esclarecimento. agora consigo editar o código conforme minhas necessidades.